# XMLHttpRequest cannot load, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present (Unable to read Ajax response in JavaScript/jQuery )

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I'm sending an Ajax request to server using jQuery, below is the code snippet.

```
$.ajax({                
                type: 'POST',
                url: "https://store.example.com/account?",                
                data: "cf=cw&operation=update"
            })
```

Definitely, “requested page” and “Ajax request’s URL” are in same domain. Still, Am seeing specified error message in browser console and unable read response with JavaScript/jQuery. Please help me here.

> Error message:              XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://store.example.com/account?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://store.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the requesting page and requested URL are in the same domain. Can you try accessing the url using relative path?

```
$.ajax({                
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/account?",                
            data: "cf=cw&operation=update"
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

AJAX Requests are only possible if port, protocol and domain of sender and receiver are equal,if not might lead to CORS. CORS stands for Cross-origin resource sharing and has to be supported on the server side.

> **Solution**

**JSONP**

JSONP or "JSON with padding" is a communication technique used in JavaScript programs running in web browsers to request data from a server in a different domain, something prohibited by typical web browsers because of the same-origin policy.

Example

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "https://store.example.com/account?",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        //code
    }
});
```

Hope this gives you an idea mate.. :)

Comment: Thanks, able to figure out problem with my code. It's the protocol. Interestingly, HTTP and HTTPs are treated as different protocol.