# Magnific popup not loading via AJAX and giving 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load' error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, magnific-popup

I'm trying to create a popup page using Magnific via AJAX but getting an 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load' error when the link button is clicked.

Below is the partial code for the portfolio section where clicking on the button should load `project_1.html`:

```html
<div class="masonry_items removeImgGrayFilter  portfolio_items catFilterEffect_1 ajaxPopup_gallery" data-animated-time="15" data-animated-in="animated fadeIn" data-animated-innerContent="yes" data-anchor-to="parent.parent.parent">

  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>

  <!-- Category 1 - jQuery  -->
  <!-- Thumbnail -->
  <div class="item width_1by4 hover_enable cat1 selPopup">

    <div class="item_thumbnail">
      <div class="porImgOver">
        <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
        <img class="preload" src="images/0.png" data-src="images/portfolio/thumb1.jpg" alt="image_alt_text" />
      </div>

      <div class="imageText textOnHover">
        <div class="text_field lightColorText">
          <h5>Bloc Jams - jQuery</h5>
          <h6>A fully functional digital music player similar to Spotify</h6>

          <a class="detail_btn ajaxPopup_galItem" href="project_1.html">
            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></span> 
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      ....
      
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.min.js"></script>
```

```
custom.min.js
```

```js
// magnificPopup plugin Initialization 
try {
  //Initialize Image
  $('.magnificPopup').each(function() {
    var mc = $(this);
    var tit = mc.attr("data-title") !== undefined ? "data-title" : "title";
    var typ = mc.attr("data-type") !== undefined ? mc.attr("data-type") : "image";
    mc.magnificPopup({
      image: {
        titleSrc: tit
      },
      type: typ,
      removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
      callbacks: {
        change: function() {
          this.content.addClass("animated fadeInLeft");
        },
      },
      closeOnContentClick: false,
      closeBtnInside: true,
      midClick: false // allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source.
    });
  });
} catch (e) {}

try {
  //Initialize Gallery
  $('.magnificPopup_gallery').each(function() { // the containers for all your galleries
    $(this).magnificPopup({
      delegate: 'a', // the selector for gallery item
      type: 'image',
      gallery: {
        enabled: true
      },
      callbacks: {
        change: function() {
          this.content.addClass("animated fadeInLeft");
        },
      },
      closeOnContentClick: false,
      midClick: true, // allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source.
    });
  });
} catch (e) {}

try {
  // Initialize portfolio item gallery
  $('.magnificPopup_item_gallery').each(function() {
    var mc = $(this);
    var p_items = [];
    mc.find(".i_gallery").children().each(function() {
      var mc2 = $(this);
      var tit = mc2.attr("data-title") !== undefined ? mc2.attr("data-title") : mc2.attr("title");
      p_items.push({
        src: mc2.attr("data-href"),
        title: tit,
        type: mc2.attr("data-type")
      });
    });
    mc.magnificPopup({
      items: p_items, // the selector for gallery item
      type: 'image', // this is default type
      removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
      gallery: {
        enabled: true
      },
      callbacks: {
        change: function() {
          this.content.addClass("animated fadeInLeft");
        },
      },
      closeOnContentClick: false,
      midClick: true // allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source.
    });
  });
} catch (e) {}

try {
  // Initialize inline content
  $('.magnificPopup_inline').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',
    callbacks: {
      change: function() {
        this.content.addClass("animated fadeInLeft");
      },
    },
    closeOnContentClick: false,
    midClick: true // allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source.
  });
} catch (e) {}


try {
  // Initialize popup detail text 
  $('.detail_text').each(function() {
    var cont = $(this).find(".popup_text");
    $(this).find(".link_btn").magnificPopup({
      items: {
        src: cont,
        type: 'inline'
      },
      removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation 
      closeOnContentClick: false,
      midClick: true // allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source.
    });
  });
} catch (e) {}


$('.ajaxPopup_link').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax',
  settings: null,
  alignTop: false,
  cursor: 'mfp-ajax-cur',
  closeOnContentClick: false,
  closeBtnInside: true
});


try {
  //Initialize Gallery
  $('.ajaxPopup_gallery').each(function() { // the containers for all your galleries
    $(this).magnificPopup({
      delegate: '.selPopup a.ajaxPopup_galItem', // the selector for gallery item
      type: 'ajax',
      settings: null,
      alignTop: true,
      cursor: 'mfp-ajax-cur',
      gallery: {
        enabled: true
      },
      closeOnContentClick: false,
      midClick: true, // allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source.
    });
  });
} catch (e) {}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present (Unable to read Ajax response in JavaScript/jQuery )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104251/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)